# All Stack Exchange sites unreachable/connection reset from my home ISP

Tags: support, connectivity

This is a strange error. For months, I have not been able to reach Stackexchange sites from my home connection (Starhub, Singapore). I get HTTP 101 Connection reset. I can ping Stackoveflow.com but when using telnet to manually connect with HTTP I get connection reset. It's probably not device dependent because I can't reach the site on any device at my home connection.

It works on my 3G subscription and at my work, and they point to the same IP. Anyone have a clue why this may happen? It seem to me either the ISP cuts off connections to Stackexchange, or Stackexchange resets connections from this ISP/IP range.

Trace from working 3G (removed first). Ironically my 3G is with the same ISP but takes a very different route:

--- Nice Trace to Stackoverflow.com ---

```
2) 203.116.22.194 (203.116.22.194) 82.080 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 9874] Singapore
3) 203.117.190.85 (203.117.190.85) 83.811 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 4657] Singapore
4) anutsi10.starhub.net.sg (203.118.3.162) 79.970 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 4657] Singapore
5) ge9-0.singapore2.sin.seabone.net (93.186.133.49) 76.617 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 6762] Singapore
6) pos7-0.singapore1.sin.seabone.net (213.144.176.46) 89.246 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 6762] Singapore
7) tinet.singapore1.sin.seabone.net (213.144.176.82) 90.452 ms, 12/12 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 6762] Singapore
8) xe-2-2-0.nyc20.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.181.181) 351.992 ms, 11/11 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3257] France
9) peer1-gw.ip4.tinet.net (77.67.70.194) 339.281 ms, 11/11 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3257] Germany
10) * * *
11) * * *
12) gwny01.stackoverflow.com (64.34.41.58) 331.457 ms, 11/11 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 13768] United States
13) stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12) 335.087 ms, 11/11 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 13768] United States
```

And here is on the fixed connection that does not get HTTP connectivity to stackoverflow.com . As you can see, it can connect on IP (but still not HTTP).

--- Nice Trace to Stackoverflow.com ---

```
2) 172.20.15.1 (172.20.15.1) 16.502 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss European Union
3) 172.26.15.1 (172.26.15.1) 16.117 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss European Union
4) 172.20.7.94 (172.20.7.94) 16.371 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss European Union
5) 172.20.7.70 (172.20.7.70) 28.843 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss European Union
6) 203.117.35.193 (203.117.35.193) 26.341 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 38861] Singapore
7) so-6-0-2.edge5.sanjose1.level3.net (4.53.28.1) 229.370 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
8) vlan60.csw1.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.152.62) 231.066 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
9) ae-71-71.ebr1.sanjose1.level3.net (4.69.153.5) 217.601 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
10) ae-2-2.ebr2.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.135.186) 298.774 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
11) ae-72-72.csw2.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.148.38) 302.946 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
12) ae-2-70.edge1.newyork1.level3.net (4.69.155.78) 300.939 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 3356] United States
13) * * *
14) gig2-0.nyc-gsr-b.peer1.net (216.187.123.5) 289.141 ms, 38/38 ps, 0.0% loss [AS 13768] United States
15) gwny01.stackoverflow.com (64.34.41.58) 284.903 ms, 36/37 ps, 2.7% loss [AS 13768] United States
16) stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12) 285.089 ms, 34/37 ps, 8.1% loss [AS 13768] United States
```

Comment: What does a trace route show? (A while back there was a routing issue at a carrier that impacted SO.)

Comment: Added traces above

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different MTU?  You can do this on your PC; routers generally neither split nor reassemble IP packets.

Open a command prompt as admin, and type:

```
netsh
interface
ipv4
set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1000
```

You can add `store=persistent` to the last command to make the change survive reboots.

If you have admin rights on your work PC, capture a [Wireshark trace](http://www.wireshark.org/) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you can't access some web sites, the problem is in the MTU. You can try lowering it in your modem and see if it changes something.

Comment: I doubt that it is related to this as this would affect more than just this website - most likely his ISP has screwed up the route/similar.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum When I had problems of MTU, only a small percentage of sites was affected (let's say 10% of the sites I normally visit), so it would be possible.